# Search url wp-rewrite after redirect?

Tags: url-rewriting

I started using this functions for my "search results"-page.

```
#SearchRewrite
add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'my_rewrite_rules');
function my_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite )
{
    //RewriteRule ^icerik/(.+)?$ /index.php?s=$1 [QSA,L]
    $new_rules = array(
    'icerik/(.+).html' => 'index.php?s=' .
    $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) );
    $wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
```

Also I added this line to my `.htaccess`-file

```
RewriteRule ^icerik/(.+)?$ /index.php?s=$1 [QSA,L]
```

But, whenever I search for something in my search-field the URL doesnt redirect to new URL—even though the new links actually works, I now have two links.

Example:

This is the rewritten URL: http://www.fatihtoprak.com/icerik/linux.html

This is the regular URL: http://www.fatihtoprak.com/?s=linux

My question is then: how do I make the rewritten URL display, when a user uses the search-field on my website?

**---UPDATED---**

It solved with this Plugin & Class [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/70746/7394).. Also i have another question about this. Its like ;

when i type a word with Turkish character (İ,Ü,ü,Ö,ö,ğ,Ğ,ş,Ş) it gost 404 Error page :( Do you *have any idea for this ?* Please type and search **Atatürk ve Cumhuriyet**. Also the query results hook doesn't care with spaces too (:

Comment: Thank you so much @Frederick Andersen for your grammer offers. Sorry about my bad English :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fatih,

Use str_replace for Turkish chars issue. Change code like this;

```
/*
Plugin Name: Redirect Search Results
Author: Abdussamad
Plugin URI: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/70740/search-url-wp-rewrite-after-redirect
*/
class redirect_search_results {
function __construct() {
    add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'redirect' ) );
}

function redirect() {

    if( isset( $_GET[ 's' ] ) ) {
            $turkish= array("İ","ı","Ü","ü","Ö","ö","ğ","Ğ","ş","Ş");
            $nturkish = array("i","i","U","u","O","o","g","Ğ","s","S");
            $quest = str_replace($turkish,$nturkish,$_GET['s']);
        wp_redirect( home_url( '/icerik/' . $quest . '.html' ), 301 );
        exit;
    }
}
}

new redirect_search_results();
```

Comment: Thank you so much Serkan, but got another thing is, search_query on my search.php title. I use this method `<strong><?php echo get_search_query(); ?>` on my search results page title. This title should be include unconverted the characters ? Is that possible ? Must be like Atatürk (:

Comment: Fatih, WordPress uses get method for search forms. Use `echo $_GET['s'];`. I think this code works good :)

Comment: Also you can use `<?php the_search_query(); ?>`

Comment: i just try `<?php the_search_query(); ?>` it didint display anything.

Answer (score 1):

wp_rewrite doesn't redirect. It simply parses requested URLs into query strings that wordpress understands.

You can redirect using this plugin:

```
/*
Plugin Name: Redirect Search Results
Author: Abdussamad
Plugin URI: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/70740/search-url-wp-rewrite-after-redirect
*/
class redirect_search_results {
function __construct() {
    add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'redirect' ) );
}

function redirect() {
    if( isset( $_GET[ 's' ] ) ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url( '/icerik/' . $_GET[ 's' ] . '.html' ), 301 );
        exit;
    }
}
}

new redirect_search_results();
```

Comment: So, Whats your ideas  Abdussamad ?

Comment: I have edited my answer with a redirection plugin.

Comment: I appreciate you. Thans for your help.

Comment: Also i got another problem it goes to new url but when i type a word with Turkish character (İ,Ü,ü,Ö,ö,ğ,Ğ,ş,Ş) it gost 404 Error page :( Do you have any idea for this ? Please type and search Atatürk ve Cumhuriyet. 

[This is the results page](http://www.fatihtoprak.com/icerik/atatrkvecumhuriyet.html)

Comment: Atatürk redirects properly but some other words like  için don't. The problem is that WordPress runs URLs through the sanitize_title_with_dashes function and that removes special characters. That is why searches are treated as query strings and not pretty URLs. So there is no solution that I can think of where you can have pretty URLs for searches as well as special characters in search keywords.